# Run multiple inputs into a function

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to run the coxph function for all the inputs in `myInput`? Is there a way to do this using a for-loop in R?

myInput

```
[1] "hsa_let_7a_5p"     "hsa_let_7b_3p"     "hsa_let_7b_5p"     "hsa_let_7c_5p"     "hsa_let_7d_3p"    
      [6] "hsa_let_7d_5p"     "hsa_let_7e_5p"     "hsa_let_7f_5p"     "hsa_let_7g_5p"     "hsa_let_7i_5p"    
     [11] "hsa_miR_100_5p"
```

formula

```
coxph(Surv(Time, Status)~ myInput,  data=as.data.frame(test))
```

Comment: Do you want to do this as separate (as the formula is confusing) or all at once?

Comment: I am not familiar with those functions but just a wild guess... `f1 <- function(x) {coxph(Surv(Time, Status) ~ x, data = as.data.frame(test)); sapply(myInput, f1)` ?

Comment: @akrun Yes separate tests

Comment: So are the values in `myInput` names of data.frames? It would be better if you had a list of data.frames that you could apply over. But rather than `as.data.frame()` you would need to use `get()` to get the value of a variable given the string value of it's name (but this is considered bad practice)

Comment: I was thingking something like this:

Comment: for(i in colnames(test)){
  coxph(Surv(Time, Status)~ i,  data=as.data.frame(test))
}